# Conditional modal backdrop in angular

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I'm trying to implement a modal backdrop effect in angular. I'd like to have a solid color appear when a certain modal dialog is shown that completely overlays the background screen - but I don't want this behavior for all modals (for others I don't want a backdrop).

I've added some CSS in a top level stylesheet as follows:

```
.modal-backdrop {
background-color: #008000;
opacity: 1.0 !important;
}
```

This works in that it paints a solid green background but it happens for ALL modals on my system - I need it to happen for one type only. I realise the "!important" directive prevents any CSS override, but not supplying this results in the background page not being totally hidden (it can be seen though the green color).

Any ideas on how this could be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can utilize the `backdropClass` option of `uib-modal`

```
$uibModal.open({
  ...other options
  backdropClass: 'green-backdrop'
})
```

Then in your css

```
.green-backdrop.modal-backdrop {
  background-color: #008000;
  opacity: 1.0 !important;
}
```

```js
angular.module('test', ['ui.bootstrap']).controller('Test', Test);

function Test($scope, $uibModal) {
  $scope.normal = function() {
    $uibModal.open({
      template: "<div>Hi, I'm normal modal</div>"
    });
  }
  
  $scope.green = function() {
    $uibModal.open({
      template: "<div>Hi, I'm green modal</div>",
      backdropClass: "green-backdrop"
    });
  }
}
```

```css
.green-backdrop.modal-backdrop {
  background-color: #008000;
  opacity: 1.0 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/2.5.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div ng-app="test" ng-controller="Test">
  <button type="button" ng-click="normal()">normal</button>
  <button type="button" ng-click="green()">green</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks - what is the ">" CSS operator?

Comment: `>` means only match 1 layer below. https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_gt.asp

Comment: I tried the suggestion but the new definition (.green-backdrop-modal) is not being applied, despite referencing it in the windowClass attribute of the modal.open call as suggested - any ideas? By contrast if I define a .modal-backdrop in my custom CSS then that is being observed, but of course that is then being applied to all modals in the system.

Comment: @bzo updated answer. Turns out there is an option called `backdropClass` that is more suitable for this purpose. If you place your own css below bootstrap's css, then only `.green-backdrop` instead of `.green-backdrop.modal-backdrop` would do the job as well.